# Plugin event listener not firing

Tags: plugin-development, users, events, session

In my plugin I have an `init()` method:

```
public function init ()
{
    parent::init();

    require CRAFT_PLUGINS_PATH.'/myplugin/vendor/autoload.php';

    $this->callTemplateHooks();

    craft()->onError = function(Event $event) {
        $this->logError($event);
    };

    craft()->on('userSession.onLogout', function(Event $event) {
        // do something
    });
}
```

I've got a breakpoint set on the `onLogout()` method of the `UserService` class so I can see that firing, however the breakpoint on my `// do something` line never gets hit.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Syntax looks okay. This isn't a console request, is it? What happens if you remove everything except the `craft()->on('userSession.onLogout'` bit?

Comment: @BradBell it IS firing when you hit the logout route, I was also expecting it to fire when the user session timed out, which it doesn't. I'm trying to store some additional data in session so I was trying to clear httpSession when the user session expired but I can see that instead I can use `craft()->userSession->setState()` and `craft()->userSession->getState()`. From what I can see anything set that way will be cleared from session when the user's session expires.